# If-then-else in anonymous function

Tags: matlab, anonymous-function, cell-array

I'm trying to use some kind of if-then-else statement in an anonymous function, which itself is part of `cellfun`. I have a cell array that contains a number of double matrices. I would like to substitute all positive numbers in all double matrices with +1, and all negative numbers with -1. I am wondering if I can use an anonymous function rather than coding a separate function that I then call from within the `cellfun`?

Here's the toy example:

```
mat = [2, 2, 0, -2; -2, 0, 0, 2; -2, 2, -2, 2]
cellarray = repmat({mat}, 3, 1)
```

I'm looking for something like this:

```
new_cellarray = cellfun(@(x) if x > 0 then x = 1 elseif x < 0 then x = -1, cellarray, 'UniformOutput', false)
```

I also tried this, however, apparently I am not allowed to put an equal sign into an anonymous function.

```
new_cellarray = cellfun(@(x) x(x > 0) = 1, cellarray, 'UniformOutput', false)
new_cellarray = cellfun(@(x) x(x < 0) = -1, cellarray, 'UniformOutput', false)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the built-in function `sign`, which returns 1, 0, or -1 depending on its input:

```matlab
mat = [2, 2, 0, -2; -2, 0, 0, 2; -2, 2, -2, 2];
cellarray = repmat({mat}, 3, 1);
new_cellarray = cellfun(@sign, cellarray, 'UniformOutput', false);
```

Comment: This looks like a very reasonable solution. Exactly what I need in that particular case. However, just because I am curious, let's assume the `sign` function doesn't exist. Is there a way to implement if-then-else into an anonymous function?

Comment: @Andi: Anonymous functions **must** be a single expression, and MATLAB does not know any ternary operators (like in C `condition ? true_value : false_value`). Maybe there's a complicated way of accomplishing this using multiple anonymous functions that call each other, but I'm not sure I'd want to use such a construct.

Comment: @Andi: This is the closest to the `if...else...` thing I’ve found, but doesn’t work element-wise, only on the expression as a whole, so couldn’t be used for your problem: https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2013/01/10/introduction-to-functional-programming-with-anonymous-functions-part-1/#c8d04efb-1a2d-4c35-afff-dd52e6c660d2

Comment: Interesting link. That means, if I were to rephrase my task at hand in a way that I would substitute every number greater or equal to 2 with +1 and all numbers less or equal to -2 with -1, one would probably be best off writing some kind of helper function and then call this within 'cellfun', right?

Comment: @Andi: That is how I would solve it in the general case. Keeps it readable. MATLAB allows to write private sub-functions at the end of function and script M-files, so solutions like this don’t even require a new file.

Comment: Although, replacing values larger than 2 with 2 and smaller than -2 with -2 is accomplished easily with `min(max(data,-2),2)`.